# Is there a relation between Projection formula and Verdier duality

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry

For suitable settings, $f\colon X\to Y$, $F,G$ we have projection formula and Verdier duality:

Projection formula: $Rf_!(F\otimes^\mathbb{L}f^{-1}G)\cong Rf_!F\otimes^{\mathbb{L}}G$

Verdier Duality:$Rf_* R\mathrm{Hom}(F,f^!G)\cong R\mathrm{Hom}(Rf_!F,G)$,

It seems Verdier Duality is very similar to projection formula. ($\otimes^{\mathbb{L}}$ replaced by $R\mathrm{Hom}$)

Is there some relation between these two formulas? For example, can we deduce one from another?

Comment: The functors of $G$ in the second formula are the right adjoints of those in the first formula.